# Livereload not working in Grunt configuration

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I configured a Grunt project and I am trying to run livereload.
But I cant get it to work, I included the livereload script tag in my HTML document.

Script tag inside HTML doc (body)

```
<script src="http://0.0.0.0:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Grunt file

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    
    //project configurations
    grunt.initConfig({
    
        clean: {
            build: {
                src: ['dist']
            }
        },
    
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'dist/css/compiled.css':'sources/scss/main.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        
        uglify : {
            
            options : {
                banner : "/*! app.min.js file */\n",
                style: "compressed"
            },
            build : {
                src : ["sources/js/app.js"],
                dest : "dist/js/app.min.js"
            }
            
        },
    
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    livereload: 35729
                }
            }
        },
    
    
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                    hostname: '*',
                    base: {
                        path: '.',
                        options: {
                            index: 'index.html'
                        }
                    },
                    onCreateServer: function(server, connect, options) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    });
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["clean", "connect","sass", "uglify", "watch"]);
    
};
```

I am not sure whats going on, I see that the changes to the SCSS files are being picked-up and after a hard refresh it the changes are visible, but not due to livereload.

Comment: Edit: Now it works, I added the scripttag inside the head, while I was reading that it needed to be before closing the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now it works, I added the script tag inside the head, while I was reading that it needed to be before closing the body tag.